# How can I track changes in man pages?

Tags: man

I want to know about changes of `man` pages after updating software or a operating system completely. Or get a list of revisions for a specified `man` page. This will not reread the full `man` page again and read only the changes.

I would place the directory `/usr/share/man` under VCS, but there are archive files. However, archives are not a big problem, I extract to a temporary directory.

Is there a more elegant ready solution?

Answer (score 2):

Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? Do you want this for a specific piece of software or across the board for every update/upgrade?

The way to do this for a particular piece of software is to check out the man page changes in the upstream source repository, unless the man page has been added by downstream. For example Debian maintainers occasionally write man pages based on upstream documentation, because Debian Policy thinks man pages are a Good Idea. In that case one would look at the corresponding downstream or packaging repository.

For the latter, that would be much more of a hassle. I can't think of a clean way to do it. If that is what you want, can you say what you reasons are for wanting to do this?

A really ugly way to do the latter that springs to mind is to put the man page directories under version control, and add a hook to your package manager so that a commit is automatically done after every run of the package manager (installations/upgrades/removals). This is somewhat similar to how Joey Hess's etckeeper works. It is possible with Debian's apt. I don't know about other package managers.

Comment: Something like `tripwire` could probably also work.